# getting an Undefined index: even index is defined

Tags: php, foreach

Im getting a weird error I got an Undefined index even it is defined

This is the structure of my **$list**

[image]

Then in my PHP I did this

```
foreach($list as $k => $v){
  if($v['quantity-2'] > 0){
    //bla bla bla
  }
}
```

But I got an error **Undefined index: quantity-2**

What possibly was wrong?

Comment: Do all your array elements have the `'quantity-2'` key set?

Comment: Only one of your `$list` elements has a `quantity-2` key so you'll get that warning for the other two

Comment: @Phil so how can I fix this? should I put `if(!empty($v['quantity']) && $v['quantity-2'] > 0)`

Comment: @ggorlen no only one just like the above

Comment: Personally, I'd use the same keys in each item. I see no reason to use `quantity-n` over plain old `quantity`

Comment: @Phil ok thanks for the help. Should I delete this question?